# Linq2Sql float getting mangled

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have two fields in my database that are defined as floats

```
[Longitude] [float] NULL
[Latitude] [float] NULL
```

I have added them to my linq2sql dbml and they show as floats as follows
[image]

I can see in my database there is the value -3.6607431 for Longitude however when I profile the sql (using sql express and a custom profiler tool) I see that the actual value passed in queries is 3.6607429981231689.

It seems to have lost the negative sign and had extra values added.

Is there something I'm missing does a float in SQL not map to a float like this in the dbml or is there another issue going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of `-3.6607431f` in C# is actually *exactly* -3.6607429981231689453125 - i.e. that's the exactly-representable float value which is closest to `-3.6607431`. So I think that answers the precision part - it's just a natural part of [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx). Basically, you shouldn't worry about that - unless you *need* precise decimal values, in which case you should map to `decimal` instead of `float` (and update your database schema appropriately).

The sign issue is somewhat different - and my *guess* is that you've misdiagnosed it somewhere, or you've got some code which negates things. I very much *doubt* that that's a database problem.

It's not clear from your description whether you're *fetching* results or passing a parameter in a query (you talk about a "value passed in queries" which could mean either way). If you could show the code involved and how you're diagnosing the problem, that would help.

Comment: I ended up changing the type to be a decimal in the database and this seemed to get rid of most of the problems, I'm guessing that lat/long shouldnt be stored as float as we actually care exactly what the values are, close enough isnt good enough in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are only accurate to a certain degree, and have the 'problem' you describe of having 'extra values'. This is how float works.

You should consider using decimal, or possibly double. Further reading: [What is the difference between Decimal, Float and Double in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)